# Create user and provide insert and read permission in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a user who can see only two tables (Table A and table b) even though Database is having 1000+ tables. user should have only read and write permissions into this table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like following to create user and grant the appropriate permissions.

```
CREATE USER MyCustomUser FOR LOGIN <Your_Login_Name;  
GO 
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON TableA TO MyCustomUser
GO 
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON TableB TO MyCustomUser
```

If you prefer using SSMS UI to do this, you can check the step by step configuration article [here](https://support.chartio.com/knowledgebase/granting-table-level-permissions-in-sql-server)

**Note:** To allow the user to access DB, you need to associate it with a Login.

Comment: Solution for above question                                                                                            step 1 : Before executing this query we should have a login created in db.                         step 2 : Exec the above mentioned query as per your needs.                           Thanks PSK for sharing.

Comment: I agree, that's why i mentioned in the note that user should be associated with a login. My assumption was you are already having a login available.